# How to show full stack trace upon error with python debugger in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

If I encounter an error while using the python debugger, the error shows up in a red box below the errored line:
[image]

However, I noticed this doesn't show the full stack trace that I'd see if I just run the file regularly (e.g., in this case, the error is not actually occurring at the top of the stack trace shown). Is there a way to configure this?

Edit:

I am debugging using the "Debug Python File", which is a feature of the python extension.
[image]

Comment: You are debugging? You *started* it with F5??

Comment: please see edit.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems that you can get the full stack trace by executing the offending line of code in the Debug Console, but that's not really a solution.